Why does a tentacle give me a Crowned Key?
Every time I start a new attempt in Dead Cells after dying, a short cutscene will play where a tentacle wearing a yellow raincoat(?) will pop out of the ground, slide over to me and give me a golden key called a Crowned Key, and then it’ll recede beneath the ground again.
What is the key for? Why does a tentacle give it to me? And how on earth did that even start happening?

A search for "crowned key start" got this spoilered reddit post from 2 years ago by CatSlugss, about getting the Crowned Key at the start of every run after getting it during a run:

 I was doing something for the weird guy in the sewers. And it gave me the crowned key.. where does that go to? It gives it to me at the start of every run now.

Its purpose as said by DCG-MTG 2 years ago in response:

Used to open the gate (in any transition after the second boss of a run) to the Queen and the Sea content. The key is permanently used and the gate permanently opened after the first time you open it.

How to get / how you got it initially:
https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Stilt_Village#Crowned_Key

 When meeting the Fisherman at the Toxic Sewers after receiving his letter, he instructs the player to visit Michel's house in Stilt Village. Once visited, there is a door that leading to a lore room containing an Elite Armored Shrimp. After killing it, Michel's corpse will drop the Crowned Key.

As for why you keep getting it at the start, instead of having to get it again each time, player convenience, I suppose.
